# Evaluate the following integral involving the product of a fourier transform and its conjugate

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Evaluate

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(\xi)\overline{\hat{f}(\xi)}e^{-i\xi t}d\xi.$$

I have no idea how to proceed. Any hints?